# Game Maker 8 high score table pixel size

Tags: game-maker

How big is the high score table in Game Maker 8? I wanted to make a background image for the table but each time I do the background is either too big or too small and makes it blurry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I measured the width and height of the highscore window (by taking a screenshot), and found out these measurements:

- **Table with borders:** 360 x 400 pixels;
- **Table with no borders:** 366 x 429 pixels.

I tested these sizes by creating two background images, and they weren't resized at all, no glitches were visible due to resize.